# ¿Por que una ejecución de ajax no me retorna un valor que deseo?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

La función que ejecuto de `ajax` se encarga de editar una columna en la `db` y es la siguiente:

```
function editar_parte(text, id, padre, equipo) {
    $.ajax({
        type: 'post',
        url: 'partes/editar',
        global: false,
        data: {
            'id': id,
            'nombre': text,
            'id_padre': (padre != "#") ? padre : 0,
            'id_equipo': equipo,
        },
    }).then(
        function(data) {
            if((data.errors)){
                var errores = "";
                $.each( data.errors, function( key, value ) {
                    errores = errores + value + "-";
                });
                alertify.alert('Error',errores);
            }else if((data.encontrado)){
                console.log(data.encontrado);
                alertify.notify('La parte que intenta indicar ya esta registrada en otro Item a ese mismo nivel', 'error');
                return false;
            }else if((data.correcto)){
                console.log(data.correcto);
                alertify.notify('Parte Modificada Correctamente', 'success');
                return true;
            }else if((data.ErrorSql)){
                if(data.ErrorSql.codigo==23505){
                    alertify.alert('Error',"La Parte que ha indicado ya esta registrada");
                    console.log("Código: " + data.ErrorSql.codigo);
                    console.log("Mensaje: " + data.ErrorSql.mensaje);
                    console.log("Sql: " + data.ErrorSql.sql);
                    console.log("Bindings: " + data.ErrorSql.bindings);
                }else{
                    alertify.alert('Error',"La Parte no fue agregada, refresque la pagina e intente de nuevo. Si el problema persiste contacte con el administrador del Sistema.");
                    console.log("Código: " + data.ErrorSql.codigo);
                    console.log("Mensaje: " + data.ErrorSql.mensaje);
                    console.log("Sql: " + data.ErrorSql.sql);
                    console.log("Bindings: " + data.ErrorSql.bindings);
                }
            }else{
                console.log(data);
                alertify.alert('Error','No Tiene Permisos para Crear');
            }
        }, function(data) {
            console.log('this will run if the $.ajax fails');
            console.log('Error');
            console.log(data);
        }, function() {
        }
    );
}
```

La función la llamo así:

```
let ajax = editar_parte(value, obj.id, obj.parent, $('#agregar_raiz').attr('data-id-equipo'));
console.log(ajax);
if(ajax){
    ref.edit(obj.id,value);
}else{
    return false;
}
```

Se supone que la función debería de retornarme `true/false`, pero en el `console.log(ajax)` me arroja ***undefined***. Cabe destacar que en el condicional `console.log(data.correcto)` me arroja el resultado esperado.

Noto que en la consola imprime primero la variable `ajax` y luego lo que retorna del servidor `data.correcto`. Sospecho que se debe a lo ***asincrono*** de *javascript*. ¿Como podría solucionarlo?.

**NOTA:** tengo otra función `create_parte()` y funciona de la misma manera y esta si me retorna los valores al momento.

Comment: Podrías poner el bloque de código de tu servidor, el que es el encargado de regresar la respuesta al ajax?

Comment: @JorgeMejia La respuesta del servidor me arroja correctamente lo que deseo, entra a los condicionales correctamente. Como puedes ver tengo un `console.log` para cada uno de ellos y reviso el `fiddler` y también noto que retorna lo que espero.

Comment: Veo que ocupas then por lo que es una promesa, lo que puedes intentar es hacer lo siguente poner un quinto parametro lo puedes llamar "callback" y dentro de tu "then" en las condicionales puedes poner callback(true) o callback(false), según sea el caso y tu función la llamarías así editar_parte(p1,p2,p3, function(respuesta){ console.log(respuesta) })

Comment: @JorgeMejia ¿Puedes colocarlo como respuesta y adaptarlo a mi código?

Comment: Listo, espero sea de tu ayuda.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes utilizar un callback en tu función, que va a retornar el valor del proceso de la misma.

```
function editar_parte(text, id, padre, equipo, callback) {
    $.ajax({
        type: 'post',
        url: 'partes/editar',
        global: false,
        data: {
            'id': id,
            'nombre': text,
            'id_padre': (padre != "#") ? padre : 0,
            'id_equipo': equipo,
        },
    }).then(
        function(data) {
            if((data.errors)){
                var errores = "";
                $.each( data.errors, function( key, value ) {
                    errores = errores + value + "-";
                });
                alertify.alert('Error',errores);
            }else if((data.encontrado)){
                console.log(data.encontrado);
                alertify.notify('La parte que intenta indicar ya esta registrada en otro Item a ese mismo nivel', 'error');
                callback (false);
            }else if((data.correcto)){
                console.log(data.correcto);
                alertify.notify('Parte Modificada Correctamente', 'success');
                callback (true);
            }else if((data.ErrorSql)){
                if(data.ErrorSql.codigo==23505){
                    alertify.alert('Error',"La Parte que ha indicado ya esta registrada");
                    console.log("Código: " + data.ErrorSql.codigo);
                    console.log("Mensaje: " + data.ErrorSql.mensaje);
                    console.log("Sql: " + data.ErrorSql.sql);
                    console.log("Bindings: " + data.ErrorSql.bindings);
                }else{
                    alertify.alert('Error',"La Parte no fue agregada, refresque la pagina e intente de nuevo. Si el problema persiste contacte con el administrador del Sistema.");
                    console.log("Código: " + data.ErrorSql.codigo);
                    console.log("Mensaje: " + data.ErrorSql.mensaje);
                    console.log("Sql: " + data.ErrorSql.sql);
                    console.log("Bindings: " + data.ErrorSql.bindings);
                }
            }else{
                console.log(data);
                alertify.alert('Error','No Tiene Permisos para Crear');
            }
        }, function(data) {
            console.log('this will run if the $.ajax fails');
            console.log('Error');
            console.log(data);
        }, function() {
        }
    );
}
```

Para llamar tu  funcion tienes que hacerlo de la siguiente manera, para esperar el retorno de la misma.

```
editar_parte(value, obj.id, obj.parent, $('#agregar_raiz').attr('data-id-equipo'), function(respuesta){

  //Aquí tendrias que procesar lo que quieres con base en la respuesta.
   console.log(respuesta)
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Si esperas que retorne un valor lo que deberias hacer es `async: false` para esperar que termine de ejecutarse la funcion y retornar un valor. Es este motivo el que no te devuelve un valor que guarda en `let ajax`

```
var result = false;
$.ajax({
    type: 'post',
    async: false,
    url: 'partes/editar',
    global: false,
    data: {
        'id': id,
        'nombre': text,
        'id_padre': (padre != "#") ? padre : 0,
        'id_equipo': equipo,
    },
}).then(
    function(data) {
        if ((data.errors)) {
            var errores = "";
            $.each(data.errors, function(key, value) {
                errores = errores + value + "-";
            });
            alertify.alert('Error', errores);
            result = false;
        } else if ((data.encontrado)) {
            console.log(data.encontrado);
            alertify.notify('La parte que intenta indicar ya esta registrada en otro Item a ese mismo nivel', 'error');
            result = false;
        } else if ((data.correcto)) {
            console.log(data.correcto);
            alertify.notify('Parte Modificada Correctamente', 'success');
            result = true;
        } else if ((data.ErrorSql)) {
            if (data.ErrorSql.codigo == 23505) {
                alertify.alert('Error', "La Parte que ha indicado ya esta registrada");
                console.log("Código: " + data.ErrorSql.codigo);
                console.log("Mensaje: " + data.ErrorSql.mensaje);
                console.log("Sql: " + data.ErrorSql.sql);
                console.log("Bindings: " + data.ErrorSql.bindings);
            } else {
                alertify.alert('Error', "La Parte no fue agregada, refresque la pagina e intente de nuevo. Si el problema persiste contacte con el administrador del Sistema.");
                console.log("Código: " + data.ErrorSql.codigo);
                console.log("Mensaje: " + data.ErrorSql.mensaje);
                console.log("Sql: " + data.ErrorSql.sql);
                console.log("Bindings: " + data.ErrorSql.bindings);
            }
            result = false;
        } else {
            console.log(data);
            alertify.alert('Error', 'No Tiene Permisos para Crear');
            result = false;
        }
    },
    function(data) {
        console.log('this will run if the $.ajax fails');
        console.log('Error');
        console.log(data);
        result = false;
    },
    function() {}
    return result;
);
```

Comment: Usar `async: false` es mala practica, ¿No?

Comment: @PabloContreras por que mala practica?

Comment: Por la advertencia que da el navegador.

Comment: Lo que tu necesitas hacer es retornar un valor cuando termine de ejecutarse tu tarea. Si tu tarea no termina de ejecutarse o se encuentra en ejecucion, no hay ninguna posibilidad que una tarea asincrona lo devuelva. Tienes dos opciones 1) Hacer la tarea en asincrono false o bien, analizar el codigo dentro de la misma tarea asincrona. O bien, utilizar la respuesta de Jorge